# How to prevent default PrimeNg p-tree behaviour while using keyboard?

Tags: javascript, events, primeng, keyboard-events

I use the *p-tree* component with the 'checkbox' *selectionMode*. I would like to implement my mechanics instead of the default keyboard actions (make the 'space' key to tick the checkbox, disable handling 'enter' and the arrow keys). I tried this event listener"

```
const treeNodes = this.document.querySelectorAll('.p-treenode-selectable');
treeNodes.forEach((node) => {
    this.globalListenFunc = this.renderer.listen(
    node,
    'keypress',
    (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.code === 'Space') {
            (node as HTMLElement).click();
        }
     });
});
```

But it doesn't catch the 'enter' and the arrow keys (I guess the *p-tree* stops propagation of the event somehow). How can I change it? Or is there any other way to implement my custom keyboard mechanics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override default TreeNode `onKeyDown` prototype event like this

```
UITreeNode.prototype.onKeyDown = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.code === 'Space') {
    this.tree.onNodeClick(e, this.node);
  }
  console.log('Override default on keydown event');
};
```

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treeselection-demo-mnko4m?file=src/app/app.component.ts)